# Qual è la differenza semantica fra appurare e constatare?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, verbs, difference

Guardando sul dizionario (sia quello cartaceo che su Google) ho notato che questi due verbi sono dati per sinonimi.

Ora, non essendo madrelingua e non avendo una piena conoscenza di tutte le sfumature di significato non sono riuscito a chiarire questo dubbio che vi andrò ad esporre.

"Appurare" dovrebbe stare per "accertare",  "verificare", l'utilizzo di questo verbo pressuppone che non si sia certo di un qualcosa.

Esempio:

> Ho appurato l'esattezza di questa teoria.

Il senso della frase dovrebbe essere questo:
"Ho verificato/valutato l'esattezza di questa teoria".

Quindi il verbo "appurare" si dovrebbe usare quando c'è un dubbio e si vuole verificare se un qualcosa sia vero o falso.
Questo qualcosa potrebbe rivelarsi vero o anche falso, in questo caso una teoria.

Passiamo adesso al verbo "constatare".

Esempio con la stessa frase:

> Ho constatato l'esattezza della teoria.

Il verbo "constatare" invece mi dà l'impressione di non mettere un dubbio la cosa, bensì confermare e dimostrare, dare conferma del fatto e non investigare sulla veridicità, ma riconoscere come vero un qualcosa che è stato verificato in precedenza e il riscontro è stato favorevole, ovvero la teoria che si è rivelata esatta.

Mi scuso per la lunghezza di questo testo, ma ecco la mia domanda:

È corretto il mio punto di vista riguardo all'utilizzo dei due verbi?

Grazie mille in anticipo a chi mi aiuterà.

Answer (score 4):

Io direi che la differenza tra i due verbi è sottile, ma *appurare* veicola maggiormente una volontà di azione, mentre *constatare* mi sembra più passivo. In questa frase, abbastanza comune:

> Ho constatato, a mie spese, che non era così

è evidente una specie di passività del soggetto (che avrebbe volentieri evitato di "constatare"; la stessa frase con il verbo appurare:

> Ho appurato, a mie spese, che non era così

mi comunica la volontà di andare a fondo della questione. Anche la radice del verbo, che somiglia a "depurare", indica l'azione di sfrondare dalle falsità per arrivare alla pura verità.

Guardando le traduzioni in Inglese, constatare (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/italian-english/constatare) è tradotto con *notice, observe* (passività), mentre appurare (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/italian-english/appurare) è tradotto con *check, verify* (attività).

Answer (score 3):

Il dizionario dei sinonimi Rizzoli https://dizionari.corriere.it dà

> **appurare**
>   accertare, verificare, assodare, controllare, constatare, chiarire.
>
> **constatare**
>   stabilire, accertare, verificare, appurare, assodare, prendere atto, osservare, notare, riscontrare, rilevare.

Il dizionario di italiano alla stessa pagina dà

> **appurare**
>   Accertare qualcosa, controllarne la veridicità: a. lo svolgimento dei fatti; anche con arg. espresso da frase interrogativa: a. chi ha sbagliato
>
> **constatare**
>   Accertare, verificare personalmente qualcosa; prendere atto di qualcosa: ho constatato la tua assenza alla riunione di ieri; anche con argomento espresso da frase (introdotta da che o di): ho constatato che ieri eri assente; constatarono di avere perso

Direi che la tua congettura è parzialmente vera: *constatare* ha anche un significato di *prendere atto* che *appurare* non ha.

Il dizionario Treccani concorda, dando per *constatare*, oltre che il significato di *appurare*, *verificare*,

> Più genericamente, acquisire cognizione certa di un fatto, di una realtà: *non posso non rammaricarmi, nel c. come sperperi il denaro.*